# Flutter Dart Try Catch Exception Line Number

Tags: flutter, dart

how can i know the line number of the caught Exception 
inside try, catch ?
here is my code:

```
try{
//your code here
} catch (Exception) {
    print('Exception '+Exception.toString());

  }
```

Comment: use `catch (e, s)` instead of `catch (e)` - here `s` is a complete stack trace where your exception occurs

Comment: @pskink and what ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
try{
//your code here
} catch (e, stacktrace) {
    print('Exception: ' + e.toString());
    print('Stacktrace: ' + stacktrace.toString());
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Well, after 2 years this answer saved my life and this won't need to much explanation. From the docs:

"A StackTrace is intended to convey information to the user about the call sequence that triggered an exception."


With another words: when getting an exception on a try/catch block, this will print on the console the file, line and model/function/condition that triggered the exception.